# background image on nav bar

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to make a nav bar. Pretty standard white text over a grey box for each link. But I want to have a background image of a small arrow poking out the bottom of the box. The arrow is the same grey as the box background. but of course when I try to position it over the box It goes over the area and ni longer visable. here is my code (sass shorthand)

```
    background: url('images/arrow') 1px 1px  $faint-grey;
```

Comment: Can you put the corresponding html and css in a jsfiddle.  Seeing your html would help a lot.

Comment: I have been saved by cssarrow! thanks anyhoo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the magic of CSS arrow please:
http://cssarrowplease.com/